# Generate correlated data using numpy function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray x = [67 21 80 36 53 90 82 36 95 56 41 20 49 93 79 37 95 42 76 90]. Is there any function in numpy to generate another ndarray y which has a specific correlation(for example 0.8) with x?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html